# Old Server 2019 Domain Controller Completely Crashed

Tags: domain, controller, help

We had a Windows Server STD 2019 and it took a lightning strike and destroyed Hard Drive VM data
Could not recover.

New Setup in place with Exact Same Server OS. The exact Same Domain Controller Name.
Rebuilt Active User Directory on New Server.  NO VM just installed Server STD 2019 OS Directly to SSD Drive for easier Recovery and Backup in the Future

The Issue now: I Need to get all Client Computers signed into New Domain Controller. Need to know the Best way to go about this? Is there any Software available to do this or assist with this?  Any help appreciated

Comment: “Is there any Software available to do this or assist with this? “ - There isn’t but questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope. Furthermore, your clients are not aware the DC failed. So you have to join those clients to what’s essentially a new domain. Proper and complete backups would have prevented the need to do that.